Increase in response time of a node server in node alpine image
We have an orchestration layer for our frontend where we run our node server in a docker container.
In a bid to optimise it, we changed our image from node:18.14.2 to node:18.14.2-alpine
We noticed the following:

Decrease in memory consumption
Small increase in cpu utilisation
~+15% increase in average response time
~+25% increase in average GC pause time

Any leads on what could be the possible reasons for increases in point 3 and 4?
P.S:

There are no changes to the application, only the docker image has been changed.
My hunch is differences in OS (alpine linux vs debian) but I'm not able to find material to support the same.


Alpine is using Musl Libc, which might not be as optimized as Glibc.

@AKX True, but makes me wonder why hasn't anyone raised this before.

Containers use the host's kernel, so both your images are using the same OS kernel

@AseemUpadhyay When using Alpine, you generally optimize a bit for size, not for speed. Anyway, this has been raised, e.g. here in 2019.
